# Programatically determine who created a site collection

Tags: powershell, site-collection

Is there a way, preferrably with Powershell, to determine who created a site collection? I'm not interested in who the site collection admins are, but who the actual creator of the site collection was. This is for SP2010

Comment: i have created a copy of viewlsts.aspx . I made changes to my new "viewlstsEdited.aspx" . So when i browse the  "_layouts/ViewlstsEdited.aspx" i can see who created the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://intranet.sharepoint.com/
$site.RootWeb.Author
```

where [SPWeb.Author property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.author.aspx) gets a user object that represents the user who created the website

Comment: $site.Dispose() :)

Comment: It is so easy to forget in PS, in C# it is almost built in your DNA to dispose :p

Answer (score 4):

Yes use Author property of the web object associated with site collection

```
 $siteCollectionUrl = "http://sitename:portnumber"
 $site =new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteCollectionUrl)
 $web = $site.RootWeb
 $creator =$web.Author
```