# Determine who created a Site Collection in SP2013

Tags: 2013, powershell

Is there any way to determine who created a site collection in SP 2013?

I've tried using **_.rootweb.author**, but it returns the name of the primary administrator for the site and not the admin user that actually created it.

This is a big deal because we have collections popping up and they didn't come through our admins. I need a way to trace them back to the account that's making them. The named authors/primary admins don't have the rights.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://intranet.sharepoint.com/ 
$site.RootWeb.Author
```

Hope it will works for you.

Reference Link : [Programatically determine who created a site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92402/programatically-determine-who-created-a-site-collection)